# Error in file descriptors of a pipe

Tags: c, pipe

Running this c program that evaluates the exponential taylor expansion, using a child process created in each loop that returns a digit of this sum to the parent, its leading me to a BAD FILE DESCRIPTOR ERROR, although I don't know why, I think the problem may be in the way I open and close the pipe in the loop and such.

My code is :

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()  
{int i; pid_t id;
int count=1;
int fact=1;
int N;
double S=1;double s1=0; double div;double x;
int p[2];

printf("Input x and N : \n");
scanf("%lf %d",&x,&N);
if(pipe(p) == -1)
{perror("Error opening pipe");
return -1; }
 else{ 
 for(i=1;i<=N;i++)
 {  id=fork();
  if(id==0)
  { close(p[0]);
      while(count<i)
      {   fact*=(fact+1);
                      x*=x;
          count++;
      }

    div=x/fact;
    if(write(p[1],&div,sizeof(double))!=sizeof(double))
    perror("file writing error");
    exit(0);
  }
  else {
      wait(NULL);
      close(p[1]); \\ ***<-- Problem here*** 
      if(read(p[0],&s1,sizeof(double))!=sizeof(double))
{
 perror("file become empty");         
 return -1;}
      S+=s1;
  }}}
printf("Sum = %lf",S);
return 1;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Close the respective read/write ends of the pipe after you fork not before.

Comment: still, now both on reading and writing, Im recieving the same error message